# Get the elements from tree in multiple xml files but tree is not inside all files

Tags: python, xml

This is my code, there is something i want to ask..

```
import lxml.etree as etree
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import glob

openFiles = 'myxml/*.xml'

list = []

for xmlfiles in glob.glob(openFiles):
    tree = ElementTree.parse(xmlfiles)

    for node in tree.iter('c1'):
        branch_coverage = node.attrib.get('percentage')
        list4.append(branch_coverage)
    else:
        list4.append("none")
...
```

I want to print some elements from a tree. I have 68 xml files that I want to process. But not all the files have tree("c1"). So in else statement I try to print "none". And this is the problem, when I run my program. The output always prints "none" after it prints the "percentage"

For example

wrong output :

> none, 100%, none, 100%, none, 100%, none, none, none, 100%, none

expected output :

> none, 100%, 100%, 100%, none, none, 100%

Comment: How are you sure that your output is not right?

Comment: I already check the xml files that the output print twice if the tree exist

Comment: Please check the answer, already answered the issue.

Comment: if it print '100%' it will also print 'none'. I want if it print '100%' then goes to other files not print 'none'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because , you are putting the `else` after `for` , hence the else part would always be called after the for loop ends, because the for loop ends when its condition becomes `False` , so it goes inside the `else` part .

You need something like -

```
for node in tree.iter('c1'):
    branch_coverage = node.attrib.get('percentage')
    list4.append(branch_coverage)
if tree.find('.//c1') is None or len(tree.find('.//c1')) == 0:
    list4.append("none")
```

Comment: if tree.iter('c1') is None or len(tree.iter('c1')) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: and if i not using len like this if tree.iter('c1') is None:

Comment: Fixed, please check now?

Comment: it will show all of the output is 100%. like this 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%. theres no none

Comment: the latest is im using your code = if tree.find('.//c1') is None or len(tree.find('.//c1')) == 0:

Comment: Can you do a `print` just before the if - `print(tree.find(".//c1"))`

Comment: None
<Element 'c1' at 0x3170e10>
<Element 'c1' at 0x5852c88>
<Element 'c1' at 0x5d67d68>
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
<Element 'c1' at 0x60f02e8>
<Element 'c1' at 0x5e14240>
<Element 'c1' at 0x5899550>
<Element 'c1' at 0x6a4ba58>
<Element 'c1' at 0x6a4b2b0>
<Element 'c1' at 0x590eeb8>
...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80764/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-lalalala).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a flag :

```
for xmlfiles in glob.glob(openFiles):
    tree = ElementTree.parse(xmlfiles)
    found = False

    for node in tree.iter('c1'):
        branch_coverage = node.attrib.get('percentage')
        list4.append(branch_coverage)
        found = True
    if not found:
        list4.append("none")
...
```